# How to use if condition with foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to check if `EXPIRATION_DATE_TIME = Convert.ToDateTime(orderLineItem.ExprirationDate)` is not null inside this foreach loop.

```
foreach (var orderLineItem in order.WMWDATA.Receipts.Receipt.Details.ReceiptDetail)
        {
            var li = new DOWNLOAD_RECEIPT_DETAIL
            {             
                EXPIRATION_DATE_TIME = Convert.ToDateTime(orderLineItem.ExprirationDate),
                USER_DEF3 = orderLineItem.Invoice
            };
            payload.LineItems.Add(li);
        }
```

but if I use like this, i am getting an error.

```
  USER_DEF3 = orderLineItem.Invoice,
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(orderLineItem.ExprirationDate) != null)
                {
                    li.EXPIRATION_DATE_TIME = Convert.ToDateTime(orderLineItem.ExprirationDate);
                }
```

Comment: `DateTime` is a Value Type, therefore it will always have a value and will never be null. I think it would help greatly to know the definition of `orderLineItem` and where it gets its value from

Comment: @JayV, its coming as a parameter . for that i am using this field. public DateTime ExprirationDate { get; set; }.

Comment: What do you want to do when that field is null?

Comment: *i am getting an error.* - would you also call your car repair shop and say "Hello, is that the mechanic? My car is making a noise.." ? Tell us exactly what error. Always tell us exactly what error. If you're getting an error and youre considering leaving out the exact error message, please don't post the question until you've added it in

Comment: I would recommend following the [coding style guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names). That would likely make your examples easier to understand for other developers.